# How to iterate a for loop for a user input amount of times Java

Tags: java, for-loop, input

I want to get a user input number to print out "Color 1 Color 2..." etc. depending on what number the input is.

I want to do this but in java, and I'm not quite sure where to find it.

How to iterate a for loop for a user input in Java?

Comment: This question can be answered with five minutes of research into any beginner Java book and/or entry into a search engine.

Comment: If you're looking for a read loop to process  repeated user input, as is often the first interactive program people are asked to write,  then in Java  it's something like a int response=-1; while ( response!= 0) {response=System.in.read(); processResponse(response);} where the user typing anything other than zero is taken to be some identifiable command to the system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`java.util.Scanner` is probably what you're looking for. As for the for loop, you should google `Java for loop` and read up on how they work. Then combine the two concepts.

Answer (score 0):

That will do the work, using only standard java classes ([`java.io.Console`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/Console.html)):

```java
import java.io.Console;

public class Consoler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Console console = System.console();

        console.printf("How may times?\n");
        final String line = console.readLine();

        try {
            final int quantity = Integer.parseInt(line);

            for (int i = 1; i <= quantity; i++) {
                System.out.printf("Color %d ",i);
            }
            System.out.println();
        } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println(line + " is not a number.");
        }

    }
}
```